# How to draw a radar chart with a lot of rows (or dimensions) using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, geometry

Let's say I have such data:

```
a <- tibble(id=c(1,1.1,1.2,1.7,2,2.1,2.6,4,4.6,4.68),
            x=c(0.3,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.1,0.5,0.43,0.6,0.3,0.65),
            y=c(0.2,0.1,0.22,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.14,0.3))
```

This is just a sample, my real data is much more than this. and x+y+... = 1. I want to draw two lines: one line is for x, one line is for x+y:

```
ggplot(a) +
  geom_line(aes(x=id,y=x),color='red') +
  geom_line(aes(x=id,y=x+y),color='blue')
```

But what I really want something like a radar chart like:

[image]

You can see there is a circle with the radius to be 1. x and x+y, (maybe more in my data) are red and blue circles respectively. So, x+y must be larger than x but always in the circle because x+y+...=1. My data has a lot of ids, so it is not the traditional radar with few dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create radar charts with `coord_polar()` - e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(a) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(x=id,y=x),color='red', se = FALSE) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(x=id,y=x+y),color='blue', se = FALSE) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = id, y = 1)) + 
    coord_polar()
```

Note, that I used `geom_smooth` to get a closer to your intended result.

Comment: Looks like a possible answer - a full reproducible code in your answer would be great! (your main call to ggplot is missing, also the library call would be ideal. I recommend using the [reprex package](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/#reprex-pkg)

Comment: @Tjebo: many thanks for the hint - I've edited my comment accordingly (and I'll check reprex - I didn't know it yet).